# Square boxes when i apply Font-Awesome?

Tags: fonts

everyone thank you guys for answering my previous questions in the past, i want to implement icons with font-awesome in Dreamweaver.

however, when i do everything right, chrome renders out squareboxes, has anyone ever had this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

you have probably set a border on one of the parent elements. Use a tool like "Inspect Element" from the Firefox-Web-Developer add-on, to show you the css rules for the icon including the ones inherited from parent elements.

Comment: i read this http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhyDoMyFontAwesomeIconsShowUpAsBlankSquares.aspx

Comment: Avoid answering questions in comments. Use comments to ask more information or suggest improvements. The thing about Stackoverflow is that questions and answers also help others. By not answering your own question you hide valuable information form people with the same question. Put your answer in the 'Your Answer' field below. Only a link to an external article isn't enough. Links brake. Describe what you did so the answer is self contained. Also give credit. Hanselman.com will be happy with the extra traffic. With useful answers you earn reputation. Gaining rep gives you extra SO features.